# What is $\lim_{x\to ∞}{(1+x)^k - x^k}\;\;?$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to ∞}{(1+x)^k - x^k}$

Can anyone help me with how do you calculate this? If there's no real info about the k parameter?

Also, what are the curly parentheses for? I never seen them before.

Comment: Looks like $k$ is a constant, the value of $k$ does not matter here

Comment: The curly brackets { and } act as regular parentheses. They are used to make it easier to make out which parenthesis matches which. If they had written ((1+x)^k - x^k) instead, one might argue that it would've been slightly more difficult to read.

Comment: Do you know some of the terms in the expansion of $(1+x)^k$?

Comment: @KSplitX the value of $k$ definitely matters here. What would you get if $k=-2+i$?

Comment: @TonyS.F. May we assume its a natural number?

Answer (score 2):

The curled braces indicate that you are taking the limit of the whole expression within. You can just as easily use parentheses if you feel like it. Since there is no info about $k$ there is not really anything we can do. We need to know at least that $k$ is a real number and in particular it'd be nice if it was a positive integer or something like that. If it is a positive integer greater than $1$ then the limit will be $\infty$ since we have (using the binomial theorem),

$$(1+x)^k = 1^k+\ldots+x^k$$

Thus the $-x^k$ will be cancelled out and the remaining terms are positive and grow to infinity.

If $k=1$ then we will just have $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} 1=1$. The $k=0$ case is also obvious.

Comment: Why "If k=1 then we will just have limx→∞1=1"? I'm sorry, I just can't get my mind around it.

Comment: If $k=1$ then we have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (1+x)^1 -x^1 =\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}1+x-x= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}1=1$. The function $f(x) = 1$ is constant, it doesn't care what value of $x$ you input; it always outputs $1$. So even if you let $x$ grow to infinity, it will still give you $1$ as its output.

Comment: You mean "limit will be $\infty$", not 0.

Comment: @martycohen yes that slipped through, definitely infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Tony has covered the case $k \ge 1$. Note for $k < 0$ we can use

$$\frac 1 {(1+x)^k} - \frac 1 {x^k} = \frac {x^k-(1+x)^k}{x^k(1+x)^k}$$

The degree of the numerator is $k-1$, and the degree of the denominator is $2k$, so the limit of $x\to\infty$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to ∞}{(1+x)^k - x^k}
$

$(1+x)^k - x^k
=x^k((1+1/x)^k-1)
$.

If
$f(z) = (1+z)^k$,
$f'(0)
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(1+h)^k-1}{h}
$.
But
$f'(z)
=k(1+z)^{k-1}
$
so
$f'(0) = k$.

Therefore
$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(1+h)^k-1}{h}
=k$
so that
$(1+h)^k
= 1+hk+o(h)
$.

Therefore
$(1+x)^k - x^k
=x^k((1+1/x)^k-1)
=x^k(k/x + o(1/x))
=kx^{k-1} + o(x^{k-1})
$
or
$\dfrac{(1+x)^k - x^k}{x^{k-1}}
=k + o(1)
$.